# Trying to give a constant a this.state in react jsx

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux, lightbox, jsx

So I'm trying to create an image lightbox within my const but whenever I try to set the state it won't let me and instead I keep getting an error that says that 'isOpen' is assigned a value but never used.

```
const LineItem = ({ currency, lineItem, model, prints, snapshot }) => {
  if (!lineItem) {
    return null;
  }
  const { estimates, itar, quantity, uri } = lineItem;
  this.state = {
    isOpen: false,
  };
  const { isOpen } = this.state;
  return (
    <Panel>
      <Col xs={12} sm={4}>
        <Row>
          <Col xs={10} xsOffset={1} lg={6} lgOffset={3}>
            <ModelThumbnail snapshot={snapshot} itar={itar} />
            <button
              type="button"
              onClick={() => this.setState({ isOpen: true })}
            >
              Open Lightbox
            </button>
            <Lightbox
              mainSrc={snapshot}
              onCloseRequest={() => this.setState({ isOpen: false })}
            />
          </Col>
        </Row>
    </Panel>
  );
};
```

How do I make it so that it sets the state within this `const`.
Whenever I load up the page the light-box that I want loads up, but it becomes stuck in that specific state where I can't scroll through the page with my mousepad as it still thinks the image is their even though it's not.

Comment: try just state = { isOpen:false}, without this

Comment: The error is accurate.  You aren't using the const anywhere, so don't bother assigning it.

Comment: @jmargolisvt is there a way for it to be used within the code?

Comment: @BrunoMazzardo I changed all of my values from this.state or this.setState to just state, but I still get an error that says that my 'isOpen' is assigned a value that is never used

Comment: Not sure what answer you are looking for.  Of course you can use it, but the code you have here doesn't need it.  Just delete `const { isOpen } = this.state;` and you should be fine.

Comment: @jmargolisvt I'm trying to just toggle between two different states which I would normally use this.state or this.setState for but I don't know why it won't work now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're actually not using the isOpen anywhere!
You don't need to define the constant in order to setState.

But the main problem is that you're trying to change the state in a stateless component. Try to convert it to a class that extends Component from React.

https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html